# Python: convert variables into correct format for DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, data-formats

I have 3 variables that I would like to use to build my dataset but since they are in a weird shape/format, I had no success so far. I'm quite new to this and really appreciate any help!!

The 3 variables I have are:

```
print(newspaper)
```

['Bolero']
['Schweizer Illustrierte Style']
['Bolero']

```
print(title)
```

['Schönheit und Tragik']
['magie pur']
['Das sind unsere Favoriten']

```
print(pubDate)
```

['2007-01-01']
['2007-01-01']
['2007-01-01']

It seems to like all variables are a list of lists, but I'm not quite sure. However, since the data is scrapped from a private website, I can't post the entire code here, but I hope this is already enough for you to access what the problem is with that variable format.

What I would like to have is a dataset of this format:

| Newspaper | Title | PubDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bolero | Schönheit und Tragik | 2007-01-01 |
| Schweizer Illustrierte Style | magie pur | 2007-01-01 |
| Bolero. | Das sind unsere Favoriten | 2007-01-01 |

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to convert list of list into a list.

From [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists), you can convert a list of lists into a list by declaring the following function.

```
flatten = lambda t: [item for sublist in t for item in sublist]
```

Now all you need is to create dataframe using created lists.

```
data = {"Newspaper":flatten(newspaper), "Title": flatten(title), "PubDate": flatten(pubDate)}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Comment: I tried that, but then it separated every single letter instead of separating the 3 words. Any idea why? I get something like this: ['B', 'o', 'l', 'e', 'r', 'o']
['S', 'c', 'h', 'w', 'e', 'i', 'z', 'e', 'r', ' ', 'I', 'l', 'l', 'u', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'e', 'r', 't', 'e', ' ', 'S', 't', 'y', 'l', 'e']
['B', 'o', 'l', 'e', 'r', 'o']

Comment: Can you check the type of variable `newspaper` by executing `type(newspaper)`? if does not returns `list` then try forcibly converting it into a list by executing `newspaper = list(newspaper)` and execute the code again. Hope it helps.

Comment: type(newspaper) returns this:<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>, so it seems to me like the variable consists of 3 lists.. I tried newspaper = list(newspaper) but the output remained the same..any other advice?

Comment: Okay, that's weird! What is the output of `print(newspaper[0])` and `print(dir(newspaper))`? I would suggest looking for documentation of the scraping package being used and check for equivalent function for the required format.

Comment: I used `np_elem = article_elem.find('div', class_='so_txt')` to get the elements from the html file and `newspaper = pd.Series(np_elem.text)` to extract the text. The output of `print(newspaper[0])` is Bolero
Schweizer Illustrierte Style
Bolero
and the output of the other is something really long, starting with: ['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__.Is this what you expected?

Comment: If I use my variables to create a dataset, I only get the first input of each variable.. so basically only the first row instead of all three..

Comment: Based on your reply `newspaper` object has `iter` function? I would suggest you to loop through the lists using `iter` function and experiment and fetch the list items. then you can use the above logic for creating your dataset. If it doesn't work use `getitem` or `delitem`. Hope that helps.